# How to find which column contains only one finite value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset similar to the one below where N columns have some NaNs and one has only one finite value:

```
X=randn(50,20);
X(randsample(20,10),randsample(20,15)) = NaN;
X([1:13,15:50],17) = NaN;
```

How do I find with a code column 17, i.e the column that has only one finite value among all the columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know you are looking for a column:

```
find(sum(~isnan(X),1)==1)
```

otherwise substitute the first "1" for the axis you want.